# If you are using a Facebook extended token daily, does Facebook automatically generate a new one for you, or just extend your existing one

Tags: facebook

I've seen countless questions similar to mine. But I have a **very specific** question about this.
In the Facebook access token documentation [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken) it states

> Native mobile apps using Facebook's SDKs will get long-lived access
>   tokens, good for about 60 days. These tokens will be refreshed once
>   per day when the person using your app makes a request to Facebook's
>   servers. If no requests are made, the token will expire after about 60
>   days and the person will have to go through the login flow again to
>   get a new token.

This statement generates as many questions as answers. Note I am NOT using the Facebook SDKs because mine is a server side app written in Java. So this isn't a native mobile app.

1. Does the phrase *tokens will be refreshed once per day* mean that if I use my long-lived token daily Facebook will just keep extending the expiration of my **existing** long-live
   token? Or will it want to issue me **a new long-lived token**?
2. If the answer to the previous question is that it *wants to issue me a new token* how can I acquire that new token using only my existing long-lived token? I briefly looked into the Facebook Android SDK to see how it might work and it appears that there might be some sort of callback mechanism.

When I do a debug token call on my long-lived token at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken it says it never expires. Which is hopefully true, but contradicts Facebook's documentation stating they last for 60 days.

Any specific help on my questions would be greatly appreciated.